# where to download extra files needed at runtime?

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With rosbuild, I used to download data when building and place them in the src folder. I could them find them at runtime with ros::package::getPath().

This is usually data that is too large to be hosted in the repository, like large binary configuration files. They are needed by some of our nodes, and they usually load them when they start. As such they must be accessible at run time.

Now in catkin, I am wondering where to download them and how to retrieve them at runtime. I created a cmake function based on download_checkmd5.py that creates a new target (download_extra_data). Each package CMakeLists can declare some data to be downloaded, which happens when I make that target. What's the best strategy?

I can download them to the source folder and retrieve them with ros::package::getPath(), but that goes against the principle of not touching the source folder. Also, this would probably not work if I were to distribute my package in binary form (as the ros packages are), so it does not seem like a good solution.

I can download them to the build folder, but then how to retrieve them at runtime?

I believe the best would be to download them to the devel space, right? How can I do that? Then how to retrieve them at runtime?

For the moment, as a temporary solution, I am downloading to a path specified by an environment variable, but I am looking for a cleaner solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/109761/where-to-download-extra-files-needed-at-runtime?/) by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1001 on 2013-12-12

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-12**:
My question before answering would be what kind of data are you downloading during the build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to Dirk Thomas' answer, I managed to get a solution. Here it is for reference:

1- I download the file to ${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}

2- in order to find it from my c++ code, I wrote a little helper: https://gist.github.com/bricerebsamen/8679151

---

Originally posted by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) with karma: 1001 on 2014-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When you download the file you can specify any location where you want it to be stored. E.g. when using `catkin_download_test_data` you could pass `${CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}` as the `DESTINATION` in order to place the downloaded file in the devel space under `share/YOUR-PKG-NAME`.

(Your CMake function to register new downloads should enable to specify a user defined target name for each download in order to be able to declare dependencies between targets.)

To find the resources in a scenario with a devel and source space you can't use the ros::package API. It does not know about the new workspace layout. Instead you have to options:

- you can use `catkin_find` (as a command line tool, which has various options to tailor your search criteria) or the Python API from `catkin.find_in_workspaces` to dynamically resolve the location of the resources
- or you could pass the known location from within CMake to your code via a *configuration file*, embed the location into your code (using `configure_file`) or an *environment variable* (as you did it before).

(Please consider that it might be considered bad habit if a user checks out your package into a workspace but is then unable to build the workspace without further internet connectivity.)

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-12-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-12-12**:
No c++ API for catkin_find... could it be used in launch files?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-12**:
In launch files the `$find` logic already uses catkin_find. So you can find resources in source as well as devel space. Just make sure that the relative path within the packages share folder is the same in all spaces.

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-12-18**:
Sorry but I don't understand your last comment. catkin_find returns several paths. roslaunch $find returns only one (devel path in my case).

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-18**:
`catkin_find` has several options to narrow down the search results. Depending on how it is used in roslaunch different options are passed to `catkin_find` to only find specific resources. Please see `catkin_find --help` for a list of available options.

**Comment by [brice rebsamen](https://answers.ros.org/users/597/brice-rebsamen/) on 2013-12-18**:
I could not find any doc for roslaunch $find. Could you elaborate on "Depending on how it is used in roslaunch"?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-12-18**:
You can use $find to find an executable (in a node tag) as well as find additional resources which are only used as arguments (e.g. a param value). Depending on where in a launch file you use $find "catkin_find" is invoked with different arguments.